# XAMPP MYSQL not found

Tags: mysql, xampp

MYSQL is not working when I run XAMPP, the Start and Admin buttons are also disabled. I have tried to solve it by changing its port from 3306 to 3307 but it didn't work.[here is the XAMPP Screenshot i](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAFhH.png)

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue. mysqld.exe file was accidently deleted by anti-virus in the directory C:\xampp\mysql\bin. All I did was just downloaded the mysqld.exe file and included it in the mentioned path. it worked.